# Redirecionamento 301 fora do domínio com htaccess

Tags: apache, htaccess, url, redirecionamento, redirecionamento-de-url

Possuo um domínio `www.dominio1.com.br` que aponta para a raiz do meu site e outro domínio `www.dominio2.com.br` configurado como redirecionador para `www.dominio1.com.br/novo`. Porém, gostaria que na URL o usuário continuasse a ver `www.dominio2.com.br` ..

Não conheço nada de servidor linux e tal, mas vi que isso poderia ser feito através do arquivo .htaccess, mas depois de `n` tentativas, não obtive sucesso.

Minha última tentativa foi:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio1.pro.br/novo/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dominio1.pro.br/novo/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dominio2.com.br/$1 [P]
```

Não sei se faz diferença, mas coloquei esse código antes do seguinte, gerado pelo Wordpress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /novo/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /novo/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Alguém para me ajudar?

Comment: to sem server agora, não tenho como testar. Você já tentou usar [L, NC] ou [QSA,L] ?

Comment: Cara, adoraria testar, mas eu não tenho idéia do que está falando.. Hehe Se postar o código eu testo, mas eu não tenho conhecimento em server. Apenas não esqueça que preciso manter (ou alterar) o código do Word Press, que, pelo que entendi, mantém os links amigáveis..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, você quer que o domínio 2 redirecione para o 1 ou o contrário? O que seu código está tentando fazer é redirecionar do 1 pro 2, assim:

```
http://dominio1.com.br/novo/    ====>    http://dominio2.com.br
```

(além disso há um erro de digitação, você escreveu `dominio1.pro.br`, mas vou assumir que seu código original está correto nesse sentido)

Além disso, a variável [`HTTP_HOST`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) não inclui o caminho (*path*) da requisição, de modo que uma consulta pra `/novo` terá como *host* apenas `dominio1.com.br` - e portanto não vai ativar suas regras. Para casar tanto domínio quanto caminho você precisaria de combinar a regra do `HTTP_HOST` com outra regra usando `REQUEST_URI`. Estou citando apenas como observação, pois não me parece ser isso que você quer...

Para redirecionar de `http://dominio2.com.br` para `http://dominio1.com.br/novo/` você precisa fazer o seguinte:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} dominio2.com.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.dominio2.com.br$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dominio2.com.br/novo/$1 [P]
```

Um exemplo de redirecionamento com essas regras seria:

```
http://www.dominio2.com.br/teste/    ====>    http://dominio1.com.br/novo/teste/
```

Testado usando [essa ferramenta online](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/).

O uso da *flag* `P` assume que seu servidor possui o `mod_proxy`. Uma alternativa caso ambos os domínios estejam sendo servidos pela mesma instalação do Apache é o *passthrough* (*flag* `PT`), como descrito [nessa documentação](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#old-to-new). Essas técnicas, se não me engano, farão com que o usuário continue vendo o `www.dominio2.com.br` (i.e. é um redirecionamento *interno*, e não externo).

Entretanto, o código do WordPress vai fazer um outro redirecionamento - usando somente a flag `L`. Isso causará um redirecionamento externo, o que anularia o primeiro. Nos comentários você disse que a troca do `L` por `P` causa um *loop* de redirecionamento, mas isso não é necessariamente culpa do Apache - segundo [esse artigo](https://yoast.com/relative-urls-issues/), o WordPress usa URLs "canônicas" por padrão, e sempre que ele detecta que o usuário não está usando a URL esperada ele tenta redirecioná-lo usando o código `301`. Isso pode ou não explicar esse *loop* (não tenho certeza, por isso sugiro experimentar com a opção *passthrough* também).

O WordPress não usa caminhos relativos, sempre absolutos. Parece existir boas razões para isso, segundo [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516783/520779), entretanto é mencionado [um plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relative-url/) que parece fazer o que você precisa - usar URLs relativas, que portanto não vão mudar o domínio tal como visto pelo usuário. Esse plugin foi concebidos para testes - e não para usar em produção - mas dado esse requisito de manter o domínio anterior eu creio que uma solução assim será necessária, independentemente da solução do redirecionamento do Apache.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação detalhada. Sobre usa primeira afirmação, sim, quero direcionar para `www.dominio1.com.br/novo` ao acessar `www.dominio2.com.br` mantendo `www.dominio2.com.br` na URL. Apenas me tire outra duvida para configurar corretamente: essa configuração para o redirecionamento eu faço onde? No painel do servidor eu configurei o dominio2 como redirecionador para `www.dominio1.com.br/novo`. Está correto isso?

Comment: @CassioMilanelo Que painel? Eu procurei ajudar no que pude no que diz respeito ao Apache, mas não conheço praticamente nada de WordPress... Por isso não sei dizer se isso que você fez está correto ou não.

Comment: O painel de administrador do meu servidor, a LocaWeb, no caso. Entrei em meu painel admin de sites e adicionei `www.dominio2.com.br` como redirecionador para `www.domain1.com.br/novo`, pois foi a única forma de quando alguém acessar `www.dominio2.com.br` ela ir para algum lugar, correto? (Poderia ser por CNAME na Zona de DNS também, acredito, mas acho que não faria diferença).

Comment: Coloquei o código que me falou antes do código do WP e a URL continuou a mudar para `www.dominio1.com.br/novo` após o redirecionamento. Alterei as flags `L` para `P` do WP e entrou em loop infinito. Finalmente tentei remover o código do WP e acontece o mesmo do primeiro caso, a URL se altera. Gostaria mesmo de saber se estou fazendo o redirecionamento da maneira certa...

Comment: @CassioMilanelo De fato. Sua hospedagem é compartilhada, ou você tem total controle do Apache? Em geral, é necessário usar [`NameVirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) para que a mesma instalação do Apache sirva dois ou mais domínios, mas imagino que a LocaWeb faz isso pra você automaticamente quando você usa o painel deles, não sei.

Comment: A hospedagem é compartilhada.. Um servidor compartilhado e dois domínios registrados. Não há como fazer o que preciso?

Comment: @CassioMilanelo Não tem problema, se a hospedagem é compartilhada com certeza eles estão usando `NameVirtualHost` (eu perguntei porque, se não fosse, você teria que fazer isso você mesmo). Quanto ao seu comentário sobre as *flags*, sinceramente não sei, mas você podia seguir a sugestão da nessoila e usar `[R=301,L]` e *provavelmente* ele vai manter o domínio num primeiro acesso. Minha maior preocupação são os links gerados pelo WordPress, a menos que eles sejam relativos (caso em que estaria tudo bem) alguma configuração adicional no próprio WordPress muito provavelmente será necessária.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21827/discussion-between-cassio-milanelo-and-mgibsonbr).

Answer (score 0):

A melhor maneira de fazer um domínio exibir os arquivos do outro, é usando o redirecionamento 301 que pode ser feito pelo htaccess. Pelo CNAME do host você também tem como redirecionar, mas não tem como deixar a url diferente aparecendo na barra de endereço em nenhum dos casos.
Usando o ReWrite da forma que você colocou, apenas está sobrescrevendo o dominio1/novo em cima do dominio1/novo.

Você pode tentar usar assim:

```
redirect 301 http//www.dominio1.com.br/novo.htm http://www.dominio2.com.br.htm
```

Ou desse modo, colocando o htaccess do dominio1 com esse trecho:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.dominio2.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Aqui tem um artigo que mostra como você pode usar a regra 301 para fazer o direcionamento corretamente, mas não resolve sua questão com o domain: https://gesatech.net/knowledgebase/23/Create-a-301-redirect-for-all-http-requests-that-are-going-to-the-old-domain.html

No mais, também tem esse artigo muito bom sobre redirecionamento específico para WordPress, mas ainda não resolve o teu problema de manter uma url diferente: http://www.agenciamestre.com/blogs/redirecionamento-301-no-wordpress/

Entendi que você quer deixar o dominio2.com.br como o domain na barra de endereços do site que está hospedado em dominio1/novo. O problema é que, pelo que vi você está usando WordPress, as urls não devem ser geradas corretamente e as tags de cabeçalho do seu site não vão funcionar adequadamente.
As duas formas que permitem que seja feito como você descreveu são com as tags html frameset ou iframe, muito usadas até os anos 2000.
**Importante informar que o W3C, por exemplo, [não recomenda o uso](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/frameset) desse tipo de recurso - ou seja, só use-o se for em último caso mesmo.**
Mas se você se interessou pela saída, aqui está a documentação do frameset: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html
De qualquer maneira, seu SEO vai ficar bem mal estruturado.

Comment: Na verdade nessoila, se removendo as URLs amigáveis do WP eu conseguir fazer isso, eu removo essa parte. Não me importo tanto com isso. Gostaria mesmo é de manter a domain. Sobre o iframe, realmente não gostaria de usar isso. Nem me importo com o SEO também.