# WordPress alterando URL ao acessar links

Tags: wordpress, apache, htaccess, url, redirecionamento

Tenho um domínio `www.dominio.com.br` que aponta para meu servidor e é redirecionado via `.htaccess` para a subpasta `www.dominio.com.br/novo` através do seguinte código:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dominio\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dominio.pro.br/novo/$1 [P]
```

O que mantém a URL como `www.dominio.com.br`. Perfeito, até que eu acesse algum link em minha página, pois então a URL muda para `www.dominio.com.br/novo/contato/`, por exemplo. O código no arquivo `.htaccess` na subpasta `/novo` é o seguinte:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /novo/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /novo/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Eu acredito que mudando esse código ou alguma configuração no WordPress eu resolva esse problemas, mas após algumas frustrantes tentativas, não obtive êxito.

Como resolver?

Comment: Isso ocorre porque dentro da pasta "novo/" contém outra regra de reescrita, a qual é priorizada.

Comment: Para outros entenderem melhor, essa questão é uma extensão de outra questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52572/redirecionamento-301-fora-do-dom%C3%ADnio-com-htaccess

Comment: E como modifico essa regra para não acontecer isso?

Comment: remova-a do subfolder..

Comment: Eu tentei tirar. Não encontra mais nenhum link.

Comment: não é apenas remover por completo... precisa readaptar a regra. Não espere que eu faça o seu serviço. rsrsrs eu poderia simplesmente escrever uma resposta mas não o farei pois não vi esforço de sua parte em fazer algo

Comment: Não quero que escreva uma resposta, mas também não espero que responda um comentário sem, ao mínimo, passar uma referência. Não estamos brincando de adivinhação aqui. Você não dorme comigo pra saber o esforço que fiz até agora pra conseguir o que fiz até aqui.

Comment: Não preciso dormir contigo para saber o quanto vc se esforçou. Eu meço isso baseado no que vc posta aqui. Não postou nada relevante até o momento e é essa a imagem que vc transparece. Se não é essa a sua imagem, então mude de postura, poste o que vc vem tentando fazer porque aqui também não tenho bola de cristal para advinhar o que vc estpa fazendo e o quanto está se esforçando.. Não inverta os valores.. boa sorte.

Comment: Respeito sua opinião de que o mínimo de esforço deve ser aplicado antes sair enchendo fóruns de perguntas e respeito seu knowhow como desenvolvedor, mas cuidado ao julgar a imagem alheia. Posso não ter postado nada relevante para você, mas se ajudei 10 ou 15 pessoas com minhas dúvidas, pra mim está ótimo. E se acha que não me esforcei, é porque é fácil quando se sabe a resposta e possui a teoria necessária, mas eu sou um químico com uma necessidade pontual fora da minha zona de conforto e sem base teórica. O pouco que fiz até agora, para mim, demandou horas de pesquisa.

Comment: Cássio, sugiro que evite esse tipo de discussão desnecessária. você continua desviando o foco para continuar "batendo boca". O único prejudicado é vc. E respondendo mais uma colocação sua, isso aqui não é uma competição de quem sabe mais ou sabe menos e não importa a quantidade de pontos que um membro do site tem. Isso não quer dizer nada. Não é um medidor de nível de conhecimento. Quer saber a real? Eu também não sei a solução para o seu problema mas eu sei como buscar e encontrar soluções.